# Pass external id to dynamic label

Tags: jquery, html, tags

I have made the following [JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/vt2z4/63/)

After creating a label for some reason I am only ever able to remove the first label created by clicking the 'x'. I believe this is due the same id being incremented each time.

I have therefore tried to use the `externaltagid` and setting it to true and then passing it into the function, however am unclear as to where to set it. So each time a user adds a label, the `count` variable gets incremented and is used as the id of the new label?

This is using the [Tag Manager](http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager) library.

I tried also to set the `prefillvaluefieldname:` equal to the count variable however this did not work.

How can I pass in count as the external id??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.tagsManager('pushTag',testWord);`. In your case, by calling `divFunction` on every click you are initiating a new tags manager everytime.

Here is an [example demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/vt2z4/65/)